# Modify model data before inserting into a form in Django

Tags: django, forms, models, modelform

Is there a way to modify the data obtained from the model before inserting it in the form?
Here's my model:

```
class SomeData(models.Model):
    Some_No = models.ForeignKey('SomeDef', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Some_Val = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, verbose_name=_('Some_Val'))
```

And here's my form:

```
@autostrip
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.SomeData
        fields = ('Some_Val', 'Some_No')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Some_No'].label = _(' ')

    def clean_some(self):
        some = None
        some_id = self.cleaned_data['some']
        some = models.SomeDef.objects.get(Some_No=some_id)

        return some

    def save(self, something, *args, **kwargs):
        orig_commit = kwargs.get('commit', True)
        kwargs['commit'] = False
        ri = super(SomeForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        ri.Some_No = something

        if orig_commit:
            try:
                ri.save()
            except ValidationError as e:
                raise ValidationError

        return ri
```

The data saved inside of the models is a bit different from what I want to show in the forms when these are populated with data. However, I cannot figure out how to do it in a smart way.

Answer (score 0):

Using the pre_save signal. [Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/)

Comment: Would the pre_save signal help me populate the forms with the modified data? I think I probably didn't make this clear enough: I don't want to modify the data itself, I want to modify the data inside the forms (i.e., the data displayed in the forms).

Comment: @elena what are you trying to do ?. When you call your form you can populate this with a dict. Here  "self.fields['Some_No'].label = _(' ')" it's some type of i18n ?¿.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial value in the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['Some_No'].initial = f(self.instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an initial data dictionary argument to your form, when you instantiate it into your view.